# ggplotting output from quantile gives Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '..' not found

Tags: r

I've looked at a bunch of other SO queries with the same error in the title, but if they applied to my situation, I don't know R well enough to be able to tell.

I am using the CO2 data, trying to make a chart that shows both the average Uptake and its Interquartile range.  (I've commented out the "average" chart line because that seems to be working.)  Here's some code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

dat <- data.frame(ColPlant=CO2$Plant, ColUptake=CO2$uptake)

df<-ddply(dat, 'ColPlant', function(x) c(Cases=nrow(x), 
        AvgUptake=mean(x$ColUptake), TotalUptake=sum(x$ColUptake),
        MedianUptake=median(x$ColUptake), QuartileUptake1=quantile(x$ColUptake,0.25), 
        QuartileUptake2=quantile(x$ColUptake,0.5), 
        QuartileUptake3=quantile(x$ColUptake,0.75)))

df #Display the summarised data table

combination <- ggplot() +
               geom_linerange(aes(x=ColPlant,y=AvgUptake,ymin=QuartileUptake1,ymax=QuartileUptake3), 
                  data=df, colour="yellow", size=5) +
               #geom_point(aes(x=ColPlant,y=AvgUptake),data=df,size=3,colour="red") +
               theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))

combination #Display the chart
```

The problem is, it gets to that last line and falls over.  The error is, as the question title implies, `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'QuartileUptake1' not found`.  Yet when I run `df$QuartileUptake1`, the console returns data.

What am I missing, here?  Why can't it see that variable when it can see another created in more or less the same fashion?

Comment: There is no "QuartileUptake1" in "df". It is "QuartileUptake1.25%". Same for "QuartileUptake2" and "QuartileUptake3". You can check the column names of "df".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `quantile` returns the the probabilities:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(100)
qx <- quantile(x)
qx
#          0%         25%         50%         75%        100% 
# -2.99309008 -0.61669350  0.08979677  0.66155812  2.28664539
```

These probabilities are coerced with the name you are provided. That is why "QuartileUptake1" became "QuartileUptake1.25%". One workaround is to return the quantile, without the probability associated, such as:

```
df<-ddply(dat, 'ColPlant', function(x) c(Cases=nrow(x), 
                                         AvgUptake=mean(x$ColUptake), 
                                         TotalUptake=sum(x$ColUptake),
                                         MedianUptake=median(x$ColUptake), 
                                         QuartileUptake1=as.numeric(quantile(x$ColUptake,0.25)), 
                                         QuartileUptake2=as.numeric(quantile(x$ColUptake,0.5)), 
                                         QuartileUptake3=as.numeric(quantile(x$ColUptake,0.75))))


combination <- 
 ggplot() +
 geom_linerange(aes(x=ColPlant, y=AvgUptake, ymin=QuartileUptake1, ymax=QuartileUptake3), 
               data=df, colour="yellow", size=5) +
 #geom_point(aes(x=ColPlant,y=AvgUptake),data=df,size=3,colour="red") +
 theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))
combination
```

[image]